# Pip can't uninstall this package

Tags: python, pip, box2d

I have a problem with `pip`. I want to run a program that needs `Box2d`. But when I run the program I get an error like this:

```
...(removed)...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Box2D/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .Box2D import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Box2D/Box2D.py", line 434, in <module>
    RAND_LIMIT = _Box2D.RAND_LIMIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RAND_LIMIT'
```

I decided to uninstall `Box2d` and install it again. I tried the `uninstall` command in `pip` but it wasn't able to uninstall it. (`pip` says that the packages has been removed but the `Box2d` forlder is still in the `dist-packages` folder). Shouldn't `pip` remove it with that command?
Any solution to remove `Box2d` or fix the error?

Comment: a naive way but how about to run `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Box2D`

Comment: Just delete the folder from `dist-packages`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the folder in `dist-packages`. Then make sure there are no other references to the package in `sys.path` folders:

```sh
#in 2.7.13 in `-c' mode, `print' adds `\n' even with `,' at the end
python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("\0".join(sys.path))' | xargs -0 -I ARG find ARG -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -iHe 'box2d'
```

(Note: this doesn't search `.zip`s, packed `.egg`s and such.)

Comment: This worked. I did this and then used the `uninstall` command of `pip` and then installed `box2d` with this command: `sudo pip install box2d --upgrade --ignore-in` (i don't know which one caused it to work!)